# Javascript match for eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am using match like this: text.match(v = /(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)/g). But When es-lint run it shows an error that `v is not defined`

I tried this: text.match('v = /(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)/g')

But now match is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do this:

```js
const v = /(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)/g;
/* some kind of assignment = */ text.match(v);
```

but inline. You generally should not be assigning variables while you're inside of a function call.